# Merge Two Arrays so that the Values Alternate

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge

I'm looking for a jQuery method to merge two arrays so that their values alternate:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

The result I want is:

```
var arrayCombined = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 'e'];
```

**Please note that I know it is trivial to do this in JS, however I am after a jQuery method that will do this.**

Comment: As in a jQuery plug-in? As in a static jQuery method (e.g. `var combined = $.foo( arr1, arr2 )`)?

Comment: there is no jquery method. why does it need to be done in jquery?!

Comment: Why? As you say it's trivial to do in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Why? It's not related to the DOM or something else jQuery is specialized for.

Comment: Does there have to be a jQuery way to do everything?

Comment: If it is trivial in JavaScript do it in JavaScript. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: jQuery is for DOM stuff, don't add overhead and do it in plain js - you may use underscore.js at most.

Comment: I specifically wanted to know if there was a way to do this in jQuery. At no point did I suggest that it couldn't be done without it, or that it shouldn't be done without it. Ruby has a method that does this so I was interested in whether there was an equivalent. Seems bizarre that it is deemed not to be a valid question. It's perfectly OK for the answer to be simple 'No. There is no jQuery method that does this.', but of course there are the usual slew of people desperate to make it known yet again that not everything needs to be done in jQuery, as if this even needs to be said.

Comment: It is a very good question. Don't let them bully you!

Comment: ES6 version for two arrays: `var n = (a,b)=>a.length?[a[0],...n(b,a.slice(1))]:b;` or use `var m = (a=[],...b)=>b.length?a.length?[a[0],...m(...b,a.slice(1))]:m(...b):a;` for any number of input arrays. You can use them like this: `n(array1,array2)` or `m(array1,array2,array3,array4,array5)`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `map` method:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var arrayCombined = $.map(array1, function(v, i) {
  return [v, array2[i]];
});

console.log(arrayCombined);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hmUy6/

Comment: `var arrayCombined = array1.map(function(v,i) { return [v, array2[i]]; }).reduce(function(a,b) { return a.concat(b); });` For ES5-vanilla JS

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question rather than making a predictable fuss about how this can be done without jQuery.

Comment: +1 for adding a link in the jsfiddle back here, I found it via jsfiddle first

Comment: I've generalized @jAndy 's code to support an array of arrays to merge. This is written in ES6: ```combined = arraysArray[0].map((v, i) => arraysArray.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b[i]), [])).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);``` .

Comment: array of arrays version like @GalTalmor 's: `combined = arraysArray.reduce((t, u, v, w) => u.reduce((x, y, z) => (x[z * w.length + v] = y, x), t), []);` its quick! http://jsben.ch/2ZIGk

Comment: or for just 2 arrays: `var arrayCombined = array1.reduce((x, y, z) => (x.splice(z * 2, 0, y), x), array2.slice());`

Answer (score 18):

If you *must* use jQuery, you can take advantage of their broken `$.map` implementation.

```
var result = $.map(array1, function(v, i) {
                                return [v, array2[i]];
                           });
```

jQuery's `$.map` flattens the returned array, giving you the result you want.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/8rn2w/

---

Pure JS solution:

```
var result = array1.reduce(function(arr, v, i) {
                              return arr.concat(v, array2[i]); 
                           }, []);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/8rn2w/1/

Comment: It's documented so it's not a bug

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, but it's still broken IMO.

Comment: @JanDvorak: You're far more gracious than I. :)

Answer (score 7):

Just another solution using [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var result = array1.map(
  (element, index) => [element, array2[index]]
).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note: `Array.prototype.flat() ` requires Node.js 11.0.0 or later.

Comment: This can now be done in one step with `Array.prototype.flatMap()` (with varying support)

Answer (score 5):

For those who arrive here by search engine and want a Lodash option:

```js
_.compact(_.flatten(_.zip(array1, array2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function merge(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length == array2.length) {
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      c.push([array1[i], array2[i]]);
    }
    return c;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: not complaining or anything, but this can easily be done with arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Not enough jQuery (ah, finally I have a valid reason to say that).

Comment: Yes definitely this can be done but this one came to my mind first so tried that!!!

Comment: to match the specified format, you should change `c.push([array1[i], array2[i]])` to `c.push(array1[i], array2[i])` though.

Answer (score 1):

I came here curious to see if there was a `new Array.prototype.<whatever>()` that was helpful for this - and *flatMap* is that... kinda - but I'm going to leave with the simplest, most obvious solution... 
(and a few tears that in 10 years no one else used a for loop to build a single array)

## Plain, old JavaScript

If you were merging bits of something like stereo channels, or template strings, etc, this is all you need:

```js
// Supports the two most common cases:
//   - interleaving left and right audio channels
//   - interleaving template string and values
// (right is assumed to be the same length as left, or one shorter)
function interleave(left, right) {

  var both = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < left.length; i += 1) {
    both.push(left[i]);

    // because a template string will have one fewer value
    // than it will have string parts
    if (i < right.length) {
      both.push(right[i]);
    }
  }

  return both;
}
```

```js
// a template string will always have one extra item
var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
var one = [1, 2, 3 ];

var both = interleave(abc, one);
console.log(both);
// ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd']
```

## flatMap

As mentioned in a comment, this is probably suitable:

```js
function cleverInterleave() {
  return abc.flatMap(function (val, i) {
    if (one[i]) {
      return [val, one[i]];
    }
    return [val];
  });
}
```

```js
var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
var one = [1, 2, 3 ];

cleverInterleave(abc, one);
// ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd']
```

However, this seems a little too "clever" and not as *intuitive*. Also not as efficient... but readability counts far more than efficiency for most code, so... two strikes against.

## mo' channels, mo' problems

You could also create a more generic form of this to handle arbitrary numbers of arrays, or zip up arrays of uneven lengths.

However, I'd recommend using a similar pattern, but tuned to the actual number of arrays that you need - such as 3 for RGB, or 4 for RGBA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following if you:

1. Don't have Arrays which are guaranteed to be the same length.
2. Can't guarantee the first Array will be longer than the second.
3. Don't have to depend on a library.

```js
function interleave(a, b) {
  const interleaved = [];
  const lenA = a.length;
  const lenB = b.length;
  const len = Math.max(lenA, lenB);
  let i = 0;
  while (i < len) {
    if (lenA > i) interleaved.push(a[i]);
    if (lenB > i) interleaved.push(b[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return interleaved;
}

// Examples
const sameLength = interleave([1, 2], ['A', 'B']);
const aIsLonger = interleave([1, 2], ['A']);
const bIsLonger = interleave([1], ['A', 'B']);
const aIsEmpty = interleave([], ['A', 'B']);
const bIsEmpty = interleave([1, 2], []);

console.log('sameLength', sameLength);
console.log('aIsLonger', aIsLonger);
console.log('bIsLonger', bIsLonger);
console.log('aIsEmpty', aIsEmpty);
console.log('bIsEmpty', bIsEmpty);
```

I recognise that the question posted almost 12 years ago specifically makes reference to jQuery, so you may want to choose another answer for that reason, but I have not shoehorned that into this solution.