# How do I rearrange an array with similar items so that similar items will never neighbor each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So for example if I have this array:

```
var input = [1,1,2,4,6,7,7,1];
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
[1,2,1,4,6,7,1,7]
```

The order of the new array does not matter, as long as similar items will never (or at least as seldom as possible) neighbor each other.

I can use plain JavaScript as well as underscore.js.

Comment: We also accept codes with what you have tried...

Comment: "I will also accept answers..."? You are on the wrong site, my friend. You need to have done the minimum work yourself before we'll help you with your code. That you've been a member here for 4 years and don't know this is stunning.

Comment: I normally agree 100% that this isn't an unpaid solution site. In this case I can see getting started on an answer may not be trivial--it almost seems like a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var input = [1,1,2,4,6,7,7,1];
input.sort()
var output = [];
var len = input.length;
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((len / 2)); i++) {
    output.push(input[i]);
    output.push(input[len - i - 1]);
}
if (len % 2) {
    var left_over = input[Math.floor(len / 2)];
    if (left_over == output[0]) {
        output.push(left_over);
    } else {
        output.unshift(left_over);
    }
}
```

Or see http://jsfiddle.net/d0j3Lfa3/1.

The solution sorts the numbers then alternates high and low.  It deals with an odd number of elements, including corner cases such as [1,1,2] and [1,2,2] where it needs to push the middle element differently to pass.  Since the input is sorted, input order doesn't affect the output.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253856/merge-two-arrays-so-that-the-values-alternate/13253936#13253936) may help simplify things a bit.