# Match String of Input to text/element and highlight reactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, meteor, underscore.js

**HTML(JADE)**

```
p#result Lorem ipsum is javascript j s lo 1 2 4 this meteor thismeteor. meteor
input.search
```

**JS**

```
Template.pg.events({
    'keyup .search': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var text = $('p#result').text();
        var splitText = text.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        var input = $(e.target).val();
        var splitInput = input.match(/\S+\s*/g);

        if(_.intersection(splitText, splitInput)) {
            var match = _.intersection(splitText, splitInput);
            var matchToString = match.toString();
        $('p#result').text().replace(matchToString, '<b>'+matchToString+ '</b>')
        }

        console.log(splitText); //check what I get
        console.log(splitInput); //check what I get

    }
})
```

I have the above code.

What I'm trying to do is matching the input field's value, and then matching the text. I added it the function to `keyup` so that this is reactive.

When the fields and text match, it will add `bold tags`to the matched strings (texts).

I think I'm almost there, but not quite yet.

How would I proceed on from here?

**MeteorPad**
[Here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/9qkuDuXB57nFDpgg8/Test%20Input%20Match)

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net/ your code ?

Comment: @MokshShah I added a meteorpad link. It's like jsfiddle but for meteorjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you seem to only be matching on whole words, although your question does not specify that.  If you want to match on *any* text in the input (e.g., if you type "a", all "a"s in the text are made bold), you can do that relatively easily using the javascript `split` and `join` String methods:

```
Template.pg.events({
    'keyup .search': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var text = $('p#result').text();
        var input = $(e.target).val();
        var splitText = text.split(input); // Produces an array without whatever's in the input
        console.log(splitText);
        var rep = splitText.join("<b>" + input + "</b>"); // Produces a string with inputs replaced by boldened inputs
        console.log(rep);
        $('p#result').html(rep);
    }
});
```

Notably, you have to replace the text on the page using `$('p#result').html()`, which was missing in your MeteorPad example.  Note also that this is a case-sensitive implementation; you can use a regex to do the `split`, but it gets a bit more complicated when you want to replace the text in the `join`.  You can play around with it on this [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/MiJLhP3HvzohNnmQX/Copy%20of%20Test%20Input%20Match).

To do this case-insensitively, the split is very straightforward -- you can use a RegExp like so:

```
...
var regex = new RegExp($(e.target).val(), 'gi'); // global and case-insensitive, where `input` used to be
```

The tricky thing is to extract the correct case of what you want to pull out, then put it back in -- you can't do this with a simple `join`, so you'll have to interleave the two arrays.  You can see an example of interleaved arrays [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hmUy6/), which was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253856/merge-two-arrays-so-that-the-values-alternate).  I've amended that a bit to deal with the uneven array lengths, here:

```
var interleave = function(array1, array2) { 
  return $.map(array1, function(v, i) { 
    if (array2[i]) { return [v, array2[i]]; } // deals with uneven array lengths
    else { return [v]; }
  });
}
```

I've also created another [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/BGyinDSsF3RknGkXi/Copy%20of%20Test%20Input%20Match%20(1)) that you can play around with that does all of this.  `lo` is a good test string to check out.

Comment: so in order to make it case-insensitive, I would use the regex and have that applied to `var splitText`?

Comment: @SangYooKim I added an explanation for the case-insensitive version; hopefully it makes sense and works out for you.