# Looping through two (different lengthed) arrays to produce an alternating output

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

What is an efficient way of looping through two arrays to produce an alternating output? In JavaScript.

If I have two arrays like this:

```
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

**NB: The arrays may not be the same length**

How can I get the following output?

> Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14

I would have thought this would work:

```
if (oddNumber.length > evenNumbers.length) {
    var large = oddNumbers;
} else {
    var large = evenNumbers;
}
for(var i = 0; i < large.length; i++){
    if (evenNumbers.length >= i && oddNumbers.length >= i) {
        console.log(oddNumbers[i] + ", " + evenNumbers[0]);
    } elseif (evenNumbers.length >= i) {
        console.log(evenNumbers[0]);
    } else {
        console.log(oddNumbers[0]);
    }
}
```

But it's pretty messy, any better way of approaching this?

NOTE: These may not necessarily be in a numerical order, or in fact numbers

Comment: what do you mean by "alternate output". is there a scheme, a pattern in which you want the output to be produced? if the arrays are unequal size, you can't print alternating output. in your own example, you had to print 10, 12, 14(in series). so do you mean you want to print them in sorted order?

Comment: @MridulKashyap I should have said alternating, i.e. one after the other (whilst they both have content - then just the longer one when all elements from the shortest have been used up)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13253936/2960707 as well. There is comment that has the vanilla JS version of jQuerys $.map

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it as follows if you just want to output them:

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
for (var i=0, j=0; i < oddNumbers.length || j < evenNumbers.length;) {
  if (i < oddNumbers.length) {
    console.log(oddNumbers[i++]);
  }
  if (j < evenNumbers.length) {
    console.log(evenNumbers[j++]);
  }
}
```

If you want to get the merge result as another array you can replace console.log with `result.push` to push result values on an array named `result` as follows:

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
var result = [];
for (var i=0, j=0; i < oddNumbers.length || j < evenNumbers.length;) {
  if (i < oddNumbers.length) {
    result.push(oddNumbers[i++]);
  }
  if (j < evenNumbers.length) {
    result.push(evenNumbers[j++]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

This way you iterate both arrays as long as one of them has an element that we haven't visited yet and also prevents iterating over the same index of same array twice. Please note that I used increment in if blocks to save 2 lines of code. You can also move them to the for loop since they won't break if statements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];

var oLength = oddNumbers.length;
var eLength = evenNumbers.length;
var n = oLength > eLength ? oLength : eLength;
var rez=[];


for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 if (i< oLength) rez.push(oddNumbers[i])
 if (i<eLength)  rez.push(evenNumbers[i])
}
console.log(rez);


var odd = ["A", "C","E","G"];
var even = ["B","D","F"];
var rez=[];
for(i=0;i<(odd.length > even.length ? odd.length : even.length);i++){
 if (i< odd.length) rez.push(odd[i])
 if (i<even.length)  rez.push(even[i])
}
console.log(rez);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function accepts two arrays and returns their interleaved values as a new array:

```
function interleaveArrays(a, b) {

  var array = [],
      limit = a.length >= b.length ? a.length : b.length;
      index = 0;

  while (index < limit) {
    a[index] && array.push(a[index]);
    b[index] && array.push(b[index]);
    index += 1;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Calling the function like so:

```
var oddNumbers  = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];

console.log(interleaveArrays(oddNumbers, evenNumbers));
```

Yields:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14 ]
```

You can then output this in your preferred manner; e.g:

```
var interleaved = interleaveArrays(oddNumbers, evenNumbers);

// as a loop
interleaved.forEach(function (n) {
  console.log(n);
})

// or as a string
console.log(interleaved.join(', ')); 

// etc.
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There will be an extra `,` on the screen. Add an `if` statement if you don't want that

```
 for(var i = 0; i < large.length; i++){
 if(i<evenNumbers.length)
    console.log(evenNumbers[i]+","); 
 if(i<oddNumber.length)
   console.log(evenNumbers[i]+","); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this.

```
large = (oddNumber.length >= evenNumbers.length) ? oddNumbers : evenNumbers;
small = (oddNumber.length < evenNumbers.length) ? oddNumbers : evenNumbers;

for(var i = 0; i < large.length; i++){
    if(small.length <= i + 1){
        console.log(small[i] + ", "+ large[i]);
    }
    else {
        console.log(large[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply merge the two array and sort it

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
var mergedArr=oddNumbers.concat(evenNumbers );
console.log(mergedArr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}));
```

See No loop.. No hassle. Very Simple

Comment: I didn't downvote you but the OP edited his question since your answer to add: "NOTE: These may not necessarily be in a numerical order, or in fact numbers". This does change the context of the question, and your answer. I think a less understanding drive-by downvoter didn't realise this.

Comment: I've responded with the same solution and i've also  received a downvote , but I've deleted my first answer

Comment: Guess they don't want the efficient way. They just want the **efficient loop**. Good luck down voters

Comment: (For clarity: I did not downvote) This works for a case where the user has elements that are sortable. Perhaps a bad example by the OP in using odd and even numbers. By the note added you may also need to consider lists such as `var a = ["Bill", "Zoe", "Anna"] var b=["Carrot", "Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Avocado"]`. Applying your solution will not correctly interleave the arrays

Answer (score 0):

A long-hand example of how it can be done. The code can be shrunk for a final solution. The basic principle I'm using is to even out the lengths to take care of the alternating then tag on the tail

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];

var oLength = oddNumbers.length;
var eLength = evenNumbers.length;

var oTemp, eTemp, remainder;

if(oLength > eLength) {
  eTemp = evenNumbers;
  oTemp = oddNumbers.slice(0, eLength);
  remainder = oddNumbers.slice(eLength);
} else if (eLength > oLength) {
  eTemp = evenNumbers.slice(0, oLength);
  oTemp = oddNumbers;
  remainder = evenNumbers.slice(oLength);
} else {
  eTemp = evenNumbers;
  oTemp = oddNumbers;
  remainder = [];
}

var final = [];

for(var i=0; i < eTemp.length; i++) {
  final.push(oTemp[i]);
  final.push(eTemp[i]);
}

final = final.concat(remainder);

alert(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work always either number Array or String Array:

```
var oddNumber = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
var evenNumber = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
var margedNumbers = oddNumber.concat(evenNumber);
console.log("before: "+margedNumbers);
margedNumbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
console.log("after: "+margedNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```js
var oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
var extraElements = (oddNumbers.length > evenNumbers.length) ? oddNumbers.slice(evenNumbers.length) : evenNumbers.slice(oddNumbers.length);
var finalArr = [];
var small = (oddNumbers.length < evenNumbers.length) ? oddNumbers : evenNumbers;
small.forEach((each, index) => {
  // merge elements in desired order
  finalArr.push(oddNumbers[index]);
  finalArr.push(evenNumbers[index]);
})
finalArr = finalArr.concat(extraElements);
alert(finalArr);
```

Extract the extra elements which makes both array of same length. Then, in a simple iteration, push elements from both array with same index.