# Is there a good way to merge arrays by index?

Tags: javascript

Given two arbitrary arrays a and b, how best might you merge them to get the following result:

```
var a = [1, 3, 5, 7];
var b = [2, 4, 6];
var c = merge(a,b); // c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

or

```
var a = ["string1", "string2"];
var b = ["string3"];
var c = merge(a,b); // c = ["string1", "string3", "string2"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "by index"?

Comment: I suspect, the values are just placeholders to demonstrate the position in the result. In this case, I am afraid you have to implement some iteration "by hand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer to a similar question is probably what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253941/9796174).

```
var c = a.reduce(function(arr, v, i) {
                          return arr.concat(v, b[i]); 
                       }, []);
```

[The previous author also provided a demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8rn2w/1/)

Comment: While this may answer the question, please don't just repost another user's answer. If the question is a duplicate, vote to close it as such, or leave a comment with the links if you can't vote.

Comment: I considered flagging it as a duplicate, but the other user's question was slightly different (they specifically wanted a jQuery solution), whereas OP seemed to be looking for a pure JS solution. Since the other question did have the answer I would presume OP was looking for, but that answer was not flagged, I linked in the answer from further down the page which directly answered the question (while including the source as well). I credited the author and linked their post and demo -- in no way pretending that it was my own work.